# How to get started using the RevoScaleR library in R?

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I've installed Microsoft R Client, however when I write

```
require("RevoScaleR")
```

and something like

```
conn <- "Driver=SQL Server; Server=CZPHADDWH01/DEV; Database=DWH_Staging; trusted_connection=true"

sqlWait <- TRUE;
sqlConsoleOutput <- FALSE;
cc <- RxInSqlServer(connectionString = conn, wait = sqlWait)
rxSetComputeContext(cc)
```

it returns

> Loading required package: RevoScaleR Error in
>   RxInSqlServer(connectionString = conn, wait = sqlWait) :    could not
>   find function "RxInSqlServer" In addition:  Warning message: In
>   library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE,
>   logical.return = TRUE,  :
>
> there is no package called 'RevoScaleR'
>   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had issues with this as well...look for the location of the installed package `RevoScaleR`...make sure it matches your `getwd`. My separate instance of R installed my packages in a different location.

Comment: @pyll It indeed has been not. However, I'm very new to R. I've installed the R Client into my project directory set as getwd, but still nothing.

Comment: so you have installed the package....correct? `install.packages('RevoScaleR')`

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio with R Tools, so mine wd path looks like /visual studio 2015/projects/HelloR

Comment: R Tools -> Windows -> Packages....is `RevoScaleR` green and does the location look correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149826/discussion-between-pyll-and-stanislav-jirak).